# Brother MFC-J625DW AIO Network Scan Hang - Specific Use Case

Tags: networking, drivers, scripts, scanner

Ubuntu Server Version
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:        18.10
Codename:       cosmic

I have been working through problems with the scanner and think I have it narrowed down to one specific issue.

I am using the scan to pdf script provided by brother [here](https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn5.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on#Inst7).

The scanner works fine except in one circumstance.  When I press the scan key it will scan but if the scanner "times out" at the next page prompt on the scanner, scanadf in the scan script hangs.

I think because this is all initiated by the brscan-skey program, as long as scanadf is hung, the computer ends up unregistering presumably because the parent program brscan-skey is waiting for scanadf to finish.  To restore function, I have to manually kill scanadf.

What I've tried:

scanadf --script-wait --> no change, still hangs

nohup scanadf with & to disown --> works but scanadf and brscan-key still hung

what works: launching a kill script on a timer so that when a scan is initiated it waits 5 minutes, and then kills scanadf.

Scanning from the ADF itself works fine when initiated from server using script, using the button and flatbed works fine as long as you remember to push the button "No" for next page.  This confirms all the basic underlying stuff is working.

So it seems that the cause is that the scanner is not sending or server not receiving the signal that there is no more coming when the scanner times out.  Since ports are open and it works in every other circumstance I think I'm correct on the cause.

I pulled out a lot of hair getting to this point.  If anyone has any solutions to solve this single use case, that would be very appreciated.